# Sjphone not connecting to astreriskwin32

Tags: asterisk

I am following this example:-

```
http://www.en.voipforo.com/asterisk/asterisk-for-windows.php
```

And for SJphone config i am using this in extensions.conf

```
exten => 6000,1,Dial(SIP/egg,10)
exten => 6000,2,Hangup
exten => egg,1,goto(6000,1) ; To be able to dial with text, "egg"
```

And this in sip.conf:-

```
[egg]                           
type=friend                     
host=dynamic                    
dtmfmode=rfc2833                
username=egg                  
secret=password
canreinvite=no                  
reinvite=no                     
callerid="Jim Radford" <6000>                   
allow=all
```

But always when i am trying to connect my SJphone with asterisk server, It always shows 'asterisk Registering with service...'. I tried with diff diff username and passwords, But not working. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asteriskwin32 is limited support version. It very specific

1) check NAT settings

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

2) check password

3) check windows firewall.